# Como fazer cada clique no checkbox valha por um número?

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para cada clique que eu der valer um por um número , tipo ao invez de eu colocar um input number ao lado do checkbox eu gostaria de fazer que cada clique eu eu der no checkebox valha por um número.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olhando pra imagem e a tomando como exemplo, presumo que vc quer associar um numero a cada checkbox para que quando pressionar o Compare, o programa saiba o que comparar pelos checkboxes clicados. Correto?

Comment: seu checkbox ta assim: Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="myvalue">.  atribui um valor para cada value

Comment: Não é que o do lado do checkbox tinha um input number e eu tirei , e queria que a cada clique que eu der no checkbox seja equivalente a um numero no input number @IsraelZebulon

Comment: pega ess codigo da resposta e implementa isso dentro da myFunction()

Comment: @IsraelZebulon coloquei não funcionou

Comment: adicionar um input ao lado e da um id pra ele....dentro da funcao vc usa document.getElementById(id).value; pra add ou pegar o valor que esta dentro do input

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução muito simplista seria algo assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="m1" value="1" onclick="myFunction('m1')">

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="m2" value="2" onclick="myFunction('m2')">

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="m3" value="3" onclick="myFunction('m3')">

<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the checkbox.</p>
 
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id).value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```